# Setting different Icons for markers in flutter google maps

Tags: flutter

I want to set multiple markers on the map from a local json file, each with a different icon. I have tried every single "solution" I could find with none of them working.

I have a list of markers which I initialize first: `List<Marker> allMarkers = [];`

Then I create markers for each entry in the json file:

```
List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);
              allMarkers = parsedJson.map((element) {
                return Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId(element['id']),
                  position: LatLng(element['lat'], element['lng']),
                  icon: element['icon'],
                  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                    title: element['name'],
                    snippet: element['description']
                  ),
                );
              }).toList();
```

finally, I add the markers to the GoogleMap using `markers: Set.from(allMarkers)`

When running this code I get the error `type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'BitmapDescriptor'.`

Layout of my json file:

```
[{
  "name": "abc",
  "id": "0",
  "lat": 40.7128,
  "lng": -74.0060,
  "icon": "assets/images/icon1.png",
  "description": "some sample description"
},{
  "name": "abcd",
  "id": "1",
  "lat": 41.7128,
  "lng": -75.0060,
  "type": "assets/images/icon2.png",
  "description": "some sample description"
}]
```

Both icons are added to pubspec.yaml, this is not the error.

Full `main.dart` file on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/QNFWcszA

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply BitmapDescriptor to icon. You can do it as following:

```
icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(
      await getBytesFromAsset('asset/icons/ic_car_top_view.png', 70)),
```

and

```
Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(String path, int width) async {
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(),
    targetWidth: width);
ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))!
    .buffer
    .asUint8List();
```

}

for more detailed information, refer following link

[github](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/PacktPlus/blob/main/Flutter/HowtoAnimateGoogleMapsMarkerinFlutter/home_screen_full.dart)